# Passport.js redirects to "302 Found" after authentication

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, redirect, http-status-code-302

Passport.js enables to provide *success* and *failure* redirection urls upon authentication:

```
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/success.html',
                                   failureRedirect: '/failed.html'
                                 }
);
```

As far as I can tell, the redirects are always "302 Found" - however shouldn't they be "303 See Other"? since as per [RFC 2616/10.3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.3.3)

> If the 302 status code is received in response to a request other
> than GET or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT automatically redirect the
> request unless it can be confirmed by the user[...]

**Note**: I see stackoverflow also replies to login with 302 so it may be a widespread and tolerated violation.

Thanks in advance for any comment or suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [10.3.4 303 See Other](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.3.3) answers this question as:

> Note: Many pre-HTTP/1.1 user agents do not understand the 303
> status. When interoperability with such clients is a concern, the
> 302 status code may be used instead, since most user agents react
> to a 302 response as described here for 303.

Also, when logging in a user, there may be an implied confirmation of redirection by the user (who chose to login).